# Choosing between "everybody" and "everyone"

Tags: word-choice, differences, one-body

When addressing a radio audience, is *welcome everybody* the appropriate word choice? Why not *welcome everyone*?

Answer (score 5):

What you have in mind should be written as:

> Welcome, everybody!

Which is equivalent to, for example:

> Welcome, Janet!

Without the comma as a sentence, it would be, for example:

> Janet, go and **welcome everybody** so they understand the party has already started.

As whether *everybody* and *everyone* are interchangeable - yes, they are. It doesn't matter which one you use in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Both forms are valid, but [Welcome everyone](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Welcome%20everyone,Welcome%20everybody&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is more common as a "collective greeting".

When reporting what the announcer did, you might say he **Welcomed everybody**, meaning he welcomed the entire audience collectively. But the announcer himself is more likely to say **"Welcome, everyone!"** because this conveys more the sense of *simultaneously addressing each person individually*, making each listener feel more intimately/personally involved.

I can't say for sure, but I think a stand-up comic might be more likely to start his act with **"Welcome, everybody!"** because he'd be more concerned with encouraging the audience to think of themselves as a collective body (who'll encourage each other to laugh at the right moments, for example). That doesn't apply to a radio show, where the audience have no feedback between themselves. The radio show host is more concerned with drawing each listener in as an individual.